# Distribution with $n$th cumulant given by $\frac 1 n$?

Tags: distributions, moment-generating-function, cumulants

Is there any information out there about the distribution whose $n$th cumulant is given by $\frac 1 n$? The cumulant-generating function is of the form 
$$
\kappa(t) = \int_0 ^ 1 \frac{e^{tx} - 1}{x} \ dx.
$$
I've run across it as the limiting distribution of some random variables but I haven't been able to find any information on it.

Comment: I cannot see that this function $\kappa(t)$ you have given has the claimed property! You should revise yoiur work. Approximating the exponential n the integrand close to zero with $1+tx$, the integrand close to zero becomes $t/x$, so is divergent. So that integral cannot represent a cumulant generating function.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen not sure I follow. Approximating $e^{tx}$ with $1 + tx$ gives $\frac{tx}{x} = t$ for the integrand. Also, according to [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5Be%5E%5Btx%5D+-+1%5D+%2F+x%2C+x%3D0..1) the function I gave has a known integral in terms of hyperbolic cosine and sine integrals. To show that $\kappa(t)$ has the claimed property just do a full Taylor series around $0$ for $e^{tx}$ and push the integral through to sum to get the Taylor series for $\kappa(t)$ around $0$.

Comment: sympy says the integral is divergent (in its own eccentric way!). But sympy must be wrong, I see it now, experimented with some numerical integration, and it works just well. Will try again.

Comment: Looking at Wolphram alphas result, it cannot be correct either, it haves a non-zero limit when t approaches zero, while $\kappa(0)=0$ clearly.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen [It does have zero as a limit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Chi%28.0000001%29+%2B+Shi%28.0000001%29+-+log%28.0000001%29+-+gamma). I promise this is a cgf.

Comment: Yes, now I believe you! But the function Wolphram alpha gives do not have zero as limit --- I asked wolphram alpha itself!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I don't really care about Wolfram's representation of it, so this is all tangential, but Wolfram gives [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Chi%28t%29+%2B+Shi%28t%29+-+log%28t%29+-+gamma) for the function, and it passes through 0.

Comment: Yes it is tangential, but let us move on:  Do you have some other information about the distribution, so as its range/continuos/discrete ...?

Comment: I believe it is absolutely continuous on $(0, \infty)$. It is realized as a limit of compoud Poisson random variables; as $n \to \infty$ a compound Poisson with rate $\int_{1/n}^1 \frac 1 x \ dx$ and jumping distribution density $f_n(x) \propto \frac 1 x I(1/n < x < 1)$ converges weakly to this distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Knowing the values of the cumulants permits us to get an idea of how the graph of this probability distribution will look like. The mean and variance of the distribution is

$$E[Y] = \kappa_1 =1, \;\; \text{Var}[Y] = \kappa_2 = \frac 12$$

while its skewness and excess kurtosis coefficients are

$$\gamma_1 = \frac{\kappa_3}{(\kappa_2)^{3/2}} = \frac{(1/3)}{(1/2)^{3/2}} = \frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}$$

$$\gamma_2 = \frac{\kappa_4}{(\kappa_2)^{2}} = \frac{(1/4)}{(1/2)^{2}} = 1$$

So this could be a familiar looking graph of a positive random variable exhibiting positive skewness.
As for finding the probability distribution, a craftsman's approach could be to specify a generic discrete probability distribution, taking values in $\{0,1,...,m\}$, with corresponding probabilities $\{p_0,p_1,...,p_m\},\; \sum_{k=0}^mp_k =1$, and then use the cumulants to calculate the raw moments, with the purpose of forming a system of linear equations with the probabilities being the unknowns. Cumulants are related to raw moments by
$$\kappa_n=\mu'_n-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose i-1}\kappa_i \mu_{n-i}'$$
Solved for the first five raw moments this gives (**the numerical value at the end is specific to the cumulants in our case**) 
$$\begin{align}
\mu'_1=&\kappa_1 =1\\
\mu'_2=&\kappa_2+\kappa_1^2=3/2\\
\mu'_3=&\kappa_3+3\kappa_2\kappa_1+\kappa_1^3=17/6\\
\mu'_4=&\kappa_4+4\kappa_3\kappa_1+3\kappa_2^2+6\kappa_2\kappa_1^2+\kappa_1^4=19/3\\
\mu'_5=&\kappa_5+5\kappa_4\kappa_1+10\kappa_3\kappa_2+10\kappa_3\kappa_1^2+15\kappa_2^2\kappa_1+10\kappa_2\kappa_1^3+\kappa_1^5=243/15\\
\end{align} $$
If we (momentarily) set $m=5$ we have the system of equations

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^5p_k=&1,\qquad \sum_{k=0}^5p_kk=1\\
\sum_{k=0}^5p_kk^2=&3/2,\qquad \sum_{k=0}^5p_kk^3=17/6\\
\sum_{k=0}^5p_kk^4=& 19/3 ,\qquad \sum_{k=0}^5p_kk^5= 243/15\\
&s.t. p_k\ge 0 \;\;\forall k\\
\end{align} $$

Of course we do not want $m$ to be equal to $5$. But increasing gradually $m$ (and obtaining the value of the subsequent moments), we should  eventually reach a point where the solution for the probabilities stabilizes. Such an approach cannot be done by hand -but I have neither the software access, nor the programming skills necessary to perform such a task.

Comment: This is cool. Maybe I could do some kind of Edgeworth expansion as well? Actually, I have an idea of what the density looks like already (assuming it exists) since I can simulate directly from it. It is very strange - it looks uniform over some range $(0, a)$ and then on $(a, \infty)$ it decays with something like an exponential tail (it's been a long time since I did the simulation).

Comment: Thanks. Of course you can always perform an Edgworth expansion based on the cumulants, but I wonder how well it will perform, given the strange shape you describe. It would be interesting to contrast the two.Can you tell me the value for $a$?

Comment: Dug up my old code and found $a \approx 1$. If $Y \sim \kappa(t)$ then $[Y \mid Y < 1]$ is approximatey $\mathcal U(0, 1)$ and $[Y - 1\mid Y > 1]$ is approximately gamma distributed with shape $1.4$ and mean $0.64$.

Comment: What do you mean by $Y \sim \kappa(t)$?

Comment: So what does the pdf look like then? As for fitting by moments, is the fit 'robust' and 'stable' as one increases the number of moments used (4, 5, 6, 7 or 8 etc), or is it all over the place?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I just mean "$Y$ is distributed such that the cgf of $Y$ is $\kappa(t)$.

Comment: To be more blunt ... In my view, this question is yet to be resolved, and it not transparent to me that it necessarily has a robust solution.

Comment: @wolfies I agree with you on both points. My answer just described an idea for a solution. I am working on another theoretical approach also, based on the simulation results reported by the OP.